# Color Picker with opacity

Tags: asp.net

I am searching for a color picker with opacity I found a nice one by [jquery](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.aspx)

but it doesn't have opacity any idea about adding opacity in this picker or use another color picker ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but [this](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) is a jQuery colorpicker.

The 3rd example is one with alpha (transparency) values.